# Новый стандарт языка Haskell

Tags: haskell

Начал изучать `Haskell`. На сайте написано, что последний стандарт это `Haskell Report 2010`. Когда планируется новый стандарт? Или это финальная версия? Погуглил, но так и не нашёл никаких дат.

Comment: https://prime.haskell.org/

Comment: @extrn то есть в 2020?

Comment: вероятнее всего

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, что никогда. Сейчас стандарт хаскеля это по сути реализация GHC, которая основана на 2010 + многие расширения. Планировался выход в 2020, но так и не решили, что из этих дополнений добавлять, так что решили не делать новый.

https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/rk93s0/whatever_happened_to_haskell2020/

Comment: неплохо бы было дополнить ответ ссылками на источник изложенных фактов.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin добавил